# Blazor Server Webapplication: Can't contact Active Directory via LDAP when hosted as Docker Container

Tags: linux, ldap, debian, blazor-server-side, openldap

We have a (Mud)Blazor server application. We host it as a Docker Container.

To run the Application, we use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 as a runtime.
This works fine.

Now, we want to add user authentication to our project.
We want to use the username and password to verify it against out local Active Directory, ideally over ldap.

When testing the code on our local windows machines, everything works as expected.
When published as a docker image and run as a container, I get the error "This feature is not supported".

I think, I don't have a ldap client installed in my image. I think the aspnet:7.0 image uses debian.
I tried to install it, sadly i did not manage to do it correctly.

Can anyone show me the correct way?
We need to verify the username and password combination and get the groups, the user is a member of.

Any help is appreciated!